# Check if string contains word (not a sentence string)

Tags: php, string, search

I'm writing a PhP script, but for a filter I need to search for a string in a string.
this is the script I have at the moment:

```
<?php
$stringtocheck = "Schiphol-Almere C./Hilversum/Utrecht C.";
$searchfor = "Hilversum";

// do the magic stuff over here
?>
```

How do i get the script to search for '$searchfor' in '$stringtocheck'?

Comment: Have a look at [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for to find the *needle*-string in the *haystack*-string. And here the *haystack*-string is `stringtocheck` and the *needle*-string is `searchfor`.

Example of using the function:

```php
<?php
$stringtocheck = "Schiphol-Almere C./Hilversum/Utrecht C.";
$searchfor = "Hilversum";

if(strpos($stringtocheck, $searchfor) !== false)
    echo true;
?>
```

Comment: I've tried strpos, but it does not work.

Comment: oh, I made a typo it seems to work now

Comment: does it  work for you?